# Geometric interpretation of Dedekind sum?

Tags: dedekind-eta-function

Dedekind sum can be defined for a pair of coprime numbers $s(n,m)$. It appears also in the SL$(2,\mathbb{Z})$ transformation of Dedekind eta function.
Is there any geometric intuition what it is computing?